# Cannot bind parameter 'lockToken' in Azure function app in .net framework?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-function-app

I was using .net core Azure function in an app, with no problem faced, with the below code.

But when I create an Azure function app using .net framework it is throwing below error.

I tried all possible google solutions. the error is clearly because of nuget and library as same code works fine for v2 .net core function app.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "sub", Connection = "ConnectionStringSettingName")]Message mySbMsg, string lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

            
        }
```

I even tried this as well:

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "sub", Connection = "ConnectionStringSettingName")]Message mySbMsg, Guid lockToken, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
    
                
            }
```

If I took it as guid or string or vice versa, it gives the error:

> Error indexing method 'Function1.RunAsync'.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'lockToken' to
> type Guid. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.
> If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.)
> make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s)
> in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(),
> etc.).

Vice versa error:

> RunAsync: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'Function1.RunAsync'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind
> parameter 'lockToken' to type Guid. Make sure the parameter Type is
> supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
> ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
> method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
> config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue and any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The locktoken parameter that you are sending in is a string.

The error message is that it cannot bind the locktoken to a Guid.

Therefore, it is probably expecting a string that is a valid Guid, and you are sending in something else.

Comment: nope if i took it as guid or string dose not matter vise versa it gives the error :( . the error is clearly because of nuget and library as same code works fine for v2 .net core function app . kindly help. thanks

Comment: What is the value that you are sending in locktoken?